# Subreport In Reportviewer Table

Tags: c#, reporting, reportviewer, subreport

I want to show a ticket list in report viewer and provide printing feature for each ticket and the whole list and also paging the whole list to 3 , 5 or 7 segments. but I have stuck in the first step :)
I am using `subreport` in `reportviwer` in a `WindowsFormApplication`.
This is my `MainReport` and `SubReport`:

[image: sub report and main report]

This is my code after setting `ReportEmbeddedResource` :

```
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        ReportDataSource data = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(data);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubreportProcessingEventHandler);
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The code in the `SubreportProcessingEventHandler`:

```
    int i = 0;
   void SubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender , SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", (object)dr.Table));

        i++;
    }
```

Because my report should show two tickets this `EventHandler` lauches two times.Thus, I stored each row of my table(`dt`) in a `DataRow` which is named `dr`. It seems this `EventHandler` just uses only the first `DataRow` content. And the result is repetitive tickets. Here's the output:[image]

**Note:** I am completely sure about the value in the `dr`. It has been checked before.

I know I should some how tell the `SubReport` to use different `DataSource` for each ticket, but I don't know how to achieve this goal.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by passing parameter from main report to subreport
and I edited my `EventHandler` like this:

```
   void SubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender , SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt));
    }
```